# Override and extend method defined in parent class in Python

Tags: python, class, overriding

I want to redefine the method `Old.do(self)` in `New.do(self, x)` so that it takes one argument as below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Old(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.do()

    def do(self):
        print(self.a)

class New(Old):
    def __init__(self):
        Old.__init__(self)
        b = 1
        self.do(b)

    def do(self, b):
        print(self.a + b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    new = New()
```

I can do it with the [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Old(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.__do()

    def do(self):
        print(self.a)
    __do = do

class New(Old):
    def __init__(self):
        Old.__init__(self)
        b = 1
        self.do(b)


    def do(self, b):
        print(self.a + b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    new = New()
```

or I can do it with an explicit reference to the base class:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Old(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        Old.do(self)

    def do(self):
        print(self.a)

class New(Old):
    def __init__(self):
        Old.__init__(self)
        b = 1
        self.do(b)


    def do(self, b):
        print(self.a + b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    new = New()
```

Is there any other way to get the same result? Can [super()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super) do this?

Thanks

Comment: You should ask yourself why you want to override `do()` in this way, usually the new `do()` should be able to replace the overridden method (design by contract, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition#Preconditions_and_inheritance )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  do what you trying with super, like this:

```
class Old(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        Old.do(self, self.a)

    def do(self, a):
        print(a)

class New(Old):
    def __init__(self):
      super(New, self).__init__()
      self.b = 2
      self.do(self.b)


    def do(self, b):
        print(self.a + b)



new = New()
```

the first call will return 1, and the second call 3